# Giving a dog autoclaved bone

Tags: dogs, cooked-food

Can I give a dog bone that has been pressure coocked in autoclave? The bones don't hold structure at all and can be broken by hands.

Comment: How will the broken bones be shaped? Splintering?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I autoclaved chicken meat with bones.  With 120C heat (20-30 minutes) Bones crumble like cookie.  I can chew them easily and they seemingly dissolve with saliva. No taste what so ever so I usually throw them away  :P

Comment: @jare same here.

Comment: It's basically like eating styrofoam :D At least bone marrow adds some taste.

Answer (score 2):

Giving a dog "strong" bird bone is a bad idea since it breaks into sharp peaces but then giving it an autoclaved one likely wouldn't help with cleaning dog's teeth since it doesn't have any rigidity.

There is a study [Effects of autoclaving on compressive strength of bovine bones and their use as chewing agents for dogs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8223599/)

With the conclusion:

> Compressive strength of ASB and ACB was not affected by the autoclaving procedure. Although ASB presented lower compressive strength when compared with ACB, both types of bones were able to create sufficient friction and promote partial dental calculus removal. Visible injuries in the teeth surface and digestive tract injuries were not observed throughout the period of this study.

*`ASB` stands for "autoclaved bovine spongy bone" and `ACB` for "autoclaved bovine cortical bone".*